# Get Selected items from Listbox (main sheet) and display it in a listbox on Userform - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get the selected items from a listbox which is on the mainsheet and get those selected items inside a Listbox which is on a user form.

This is the Code,

```
Sub Viewselectshow()

 For lItem = 0 To Sheets("Main").Ent_ListBox.ListCount - 1

        If Sheets("Main").Ent_ListBox.Selected(lItem) = True Then

            ItemReq = Sheets("Main").Ent_ListBox.Selected(lItem)

            ViewSelectedEntitlements.ViewEntitlementListbox.AddItem ItemReq

        End If

    Next

ViewSelectedEntitlements.Show

End Sub
```

It works, But it shows a value of -1 in the Listbox on the Userform which is clearly not the Selected item. The Selected Item is a "CaraPhone". Any Suggestions, Kindly share your thoughts.

Comment: Seems like you are adressing the index and not the value try `ItemReq = Sheets("Main").Ent_ListBox.Selected(lItem).Value`

Comment: No, I tried .Value method and it didn't work for me.

Comment: ItemReq = Sheets("Main").Ent_ListBox.List(lItem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to use `ItemReq = Sheets("Main").Ent_ListBox.List(lItem)` instead of `ItemReq = Sheets("Main").Ent_ListBox.Selected(lItem)`